# How can I assign a Date Field to NULL in Flow Builder?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

I have a flow that removes the follow-up date when a case status is changed to "Approved".

Inside the flow, I have set the Date Field to equal Blank and then I update the record. The field is not updating to null. Is there another method for clearing out the field?

[image]

When I debug the flow it sets the field to null. In production it keeps it the same.

Answer (score 2):

Create new resource, type `Formula` and use `DATEVALUE("")` as formula. It will null your date field.

Comment: I did this - It works when I debug the flow. But in production, it does not update the field to null.

Comment: You need to set a flag and use Workflow Rules to update the field to null

Comment: To build on what @mascot shared, you can use a formula with DATETIMEVALUE("") to set Date/Time fields to null.

Comment: If you are debugging in a sandbox, this could be a difference in FLS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this:

1. Create a checkbox called "Follow Up Date To Null Flag".
2. In the Flow set the Checkbox to True
3. Create a Workflow Rule that Fires when the "Follow Up Date To Null Flag" = TRUE
4. Set a field update to set the date field to NULL

Comment: While that may work now, it is not sustainable for the longterm. Workflow Rules are being deprecated and your flow is able to update the date field to null.

Comment: No it cannot - I am working on this right now and this is still the same for date-time fields

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new resource in your flow with type "formula". Put the data type to "Date" and in the editor just type "NULL"[image: Refer to this screenshot for more help]